# Escape non-printing characters in a function for a Bash prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, ansi

In a Bash Prompt (PS1 variable), I'm calling a function to potentially add text to the prompt: `export PS1="\u@\h \$(my_function) \$ "`

However, the function in the prompt contains ANSI color codes that change based on the output of the function (sometimes red, sometimes green). Adding "`\[`" to the PS1 variable should escape those codes as non-printing, but if I do an `echo` in the function, the "`\[`" get printed literally in the prompt.

How can I escape these ANSI color codes from within a function for use in a bash prompt?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The *readline* library accepts `\001` and `\002` (ASCII [SOH and STX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29)) as non-printable text delimiters. These also work in any application that uses *readline*.

From `lib/readline/display.c:243` in *bash* source code:

```
243 /* Current implementation:
244         \001 (^A) start non-visible characters
245         \002 (^B) end non-visible characters
246    all characters except \001 and \002 (following a \001) are copied to
247    the returned string; all characters except those between \001 and
248    \002 are assumed to be `visible'. */
```

The *bash*-specific `\[` and `\]` are in fact translated to `\001` and `\002` at `y.tab.c:7640`.

---

Note: If you use *bash*'s `printf` or `echo -e`, and if your text has `\001` or `\002` immediately before a number, you'll hit a *bash* bug that causes it to eat one digit too many when processing octal escapes – that is, `\00142` will be interpreted as octal 014 (followed by ASCII "2"), instead of the correct octal 01 (followed by ASCII "42"). For this reason, use hexadecimal versions `\x01` and `\x02` instead.

Comment: That does it! `echo -e "\001\e[31m\002RED"` works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to resurrect an answer, but what's the equivalent on dash/ash/sh?

Comment: @Hosh If they use readline, `\001` and `\002` will work. Otherwise I'm not sure. Dash for example [definitely doesn't use readline](https://askubuntu.com/q/704688/301745).

Comment: `\001`: *SOH* (start of heading; non-visible chars), `\002`: *STX* (start of text; visible chars)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nice complete answer. I had to do a lot more digging to figure out where the \001 etc. had to go. Hope this helps.

```
# Color prompt for git
reset=$(tput sgr0)
boldgreen=$(tput setaf 2)$(tput bold)
cyan=$(tput sgr0)$(tput setaf 6)
boldred=$(tput setaf 1)$(tput bold)
boldwhite=$(tput setaf 7)$(tput bold)
boldyellow=$(tput setaf 3)$(tput bold)

PARENCLR=$'\001\e[0;36m\002'
BRANCHCLR=$'\001\e[1;33m\002'

alias branchname="git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '*' | sed 's/* \(.*\)/ ${PARENCLR}(${BRANCHCLR}\1${PARENCLR}\)/'"

GIT_STATUS='$(branchname)'

PROMPT_CHAR="\$"
PS1="\[$boldgreen\]\u\[$cyan\]::\[$boldred\]\h \[$cyan\]{\[$boldwhite\].../\W\[$cyan\]}\[$reset\]$GIT_STATUS\[$reset\]$PROMPT_CHAR "
```

The way I have it set up here, the git branch parentheses only appear if you're in a git branch, otherwise it's blank.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [grawity's answer](https://superuser.com/a/301355/365890), the following will enclose ANSI control sequences in ASCII `SOH` (`^A`) and `STX` (`^B`) which are equivalent to `\[` and `\]` respectively:

```
function readline_ANSI_escape() {
  if [[ $# -ge 1 ]]; then
    echo "$*"
  else
    cat  # Read string from STDIN
  fi | \
  perl -pe 's/(?:(?<!\x1)|(?<!\\\[))(\x1b\[[0-9;]*[mG])(?!\x2|\\\])/\x1\1\x2/g'
}
```

Use it like:

```
$ echo $'\e[0;1;31mRED' | readline_ANSI_escape
```

Or:

```
$ readline_ANSI_escape "$string"
```

As a bonus, running the function multiple times will not re-escape already escaped control codes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use them in the prompt, then you do need to do the `\[`. But if you want to use it in an echo, you have to use `\033[`.

Comment: Hmmm... Adding \033[ before the ANSI command ("\e[31m") and \033] after it seems to make the next printed character in the prompt not print.

Comment: You don't want to do \033] after it. \033[31m starts the color, after that you need to set it back with \033[0m