# Part of terminal line disappears when pressing down arrow

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I use a custom PS1 to display more relevant information in my terminal, such as if I'm in a git directory and if it's clean or needs to commit changes. However, sometimes when I'm arrowing through commands, part of the terminal line disappears:

```
@ ~/tests/testing [tests] > grunt
# up arrow, down arrow
@ ~/tests/testing [t
```

Essentially, the `ests] >` gets cut off and I'm left with just the `[t`.

Is there any particular reason why part of the line is getting cut off with this PS1 config?

Here's some additional info:

My TERM env var is `xterm-256color`. Here's my `.bash_profile`:

```
red='\033[0;31m'
yellow='\033[0;32m'
orange='\033[0;33m'
blue='\033[0;34m'
pink='\033[0;35m'
NC='\033[0m'

function is_git {
  if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

function stuff {
  if [ $(is_git) ]; then
    git_dir="$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)"

    if [ -z "$(ls -A ${git_dir}/refs/heads )" ]; then
      echo -en " [${orange}init${NC}]"
      return
    fi

    echo -n " ["
    if [ $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null| wc -l | tr -d ' ') -ne 0 ]; then
      echo -en "${red}"
    else
      echo -en "${blue}"
    fi
    echo -en "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)${NC}]"
  fi
}

export PS1="@ \w\[\$(stuff)\]\[\$(tput sgr0)\] > "
```

Comment: Would you please add your terminal type and `TERM` environment variable?  And is `stuff` really exactly what's in your PS1, or is that a placeholder for `pwd` or something else?Thanks!

Comment: Updated with my `.bash_profile`

Comment: What happens if you remove the `tput`?

Comment: I removed it but it still gets truncated

Comment: In `stuff`, the stderr of `ls` is not sent to `/dev/null`.  Don't see how that's relevant, but maybe give it a shot.

Comment: Where is `ls` going to `/dev/null`? I send a couple of the git commands to null but not `ls`. Those `/dev/null` are necessary or else the `git` commands will give me an error when they aren't in a git directory

Comment: `if [ -z "$(ls -A ${git_dir}/refs/heads )" ]; then` -> `if [ -z "$(ls -A ${git_dir}/refs/heads 2>/dev/null )" ]; then`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@i_am_root's suggestion to put the `\[` and `\]` inside the definition of `red` and the like is a good one.  However, per [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053), bash only processes `\[` and `\]` in `PS1`, not in text included in `PS1` by `$()`.  Therefore, use `\001` and `\002` (or `\x01` and `\x02`) inside `red` and the like instead of `\[` and `\]`.

Note: Per [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/301355/269989), only the escape codes should be in the `\001` and `\002`.  The text that will be visible to the user should be outside the `\001` and `\002` so that bash knows it takes up space on the screen and can account for that when redrawing.

Comment: Hmm... is there another way to handle it than splitting up the text from the formatting/color? Right now, `[tests]` appears as normal color `[]` and red `tests`, which means I'd have to split up the text to happen before and after the formatting. If I keep all of the text together, the entire text would appear red.

Comment: Using the `\001` and `\002` before and after the color codes fixed it! If you edit your answer to reflect that (since I got the info from that answer you linked, and since I didn't have to edit the `stuff` method) I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Edited - glad it worked!  Thanks also to @i_am_root for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Bash color codes, escaping characters, assignments, and such get confusing quickly.

Try this code sample which replaces the `echo` commands by adding to the `PS1` variable.

```
red='\[\033[0;31m\]'
yellow='\[\033[0;32m\]'
orange='\[\033[0;33m\]'
blue='\[\033[0;34m\]'
pink='\[\033[0;35m\]'
NC='\[\033[0m\]'

export PS1="@ \w"

function is_git {
  if git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree 2>/dev/null; then
    return 1
  else
    return 0
  fi
}

function stuff {
  if [ $(is_git) ]; then
    git_dir="$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)"

    if [ -z "$(ls -A ${git_dir}/refs/heads )" ]; then
      PS1="${PS1} [${orange}init${NC}]"
      return
    fi

    PS1="$PS1 ["
    if [ $(git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null| wc -l | tr -d ' ') -ne 0 ]; then
      PS1="${PS1}${red}"
    else
      PS1="${PS1}${blue}"
    fi
    PS1="${PS1}$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)${NC}]"
  fi
}

stuff
PS1="${PS1}$(tput sgr0) > "
```

Comment: That causes my output to become this: `@ ~/tests/testing [\[\]tests\[\]] >`

Comment: I tried removing the `e` from `echo -en` but it doesn't escape the color codes properly, so I end up with `[\033[0;31mtests\033[0m]`

Comment: See edited question.  Does removing `echo` and adding to `PS1` do the trick?