# Linux bash colors overlapping lines

Tags: linux, bash, printing

## Problem

I have a [ps1 script](https://github.com/seijihirao/dotfiles/blob/master/.config/bash/ps.sh) and it's working fine (I'm using `\[$(tput setaf x)\]`). But when I use a printf with colors I have 2 scenarios:

#### line overlapping

`printf $(tput setaf 2)HI!$(tput sgr0)`

Which prints `HI!` in green but [breaks the wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306348/long-lines-overlap-in-bash-ps1-prompt)

#### printing \[\]

`printf \[$(tput setaf 2)\]HI!\[$(tput sgr0)\]`

Which prints `\[\]HI!\[\]`

## Note

I also tried to use `echo` without success

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/301353/escape-non-printing-characters-in-a-function-for-a-bash-prompt/301355

Comment: I tried using **\001** and **\002** or **\x01** and **\x02**, and they didn't work either.

Comment: Now it prints `HI!` with 2 broken symbols

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to change my ps1 from:

```
RESET="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
GREEN="\[$(tput setaf 2)\]"

export PS1="${GREEN} MY PS1 ${RESET}"
```

To:

```
RESET="$(tput sgr0)"
GREEN="$(tput setaf 2)"

export PS1="\[${GREEN}\] MY PS1 \[${RESET}\]"
```

As to what happened behind the scenes I still don't know :(